# How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

The [Jackson data binding documentation](http://jackson.codehaus.org/DataBindingDeepDive) indicates that Jackson supports deserialising  "Arrays of all supported types" but I can't figure out the exact syntax for this.

For a single object I would do this:

```
//json input
{
    "id" : "junk",
    "stuff" : "things"
}

//Java
MyClass instance = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

Now for an array I want to do this:

```
//json input
[{
    "id" : "junk",
    "stuff" : "things"
},
{
    "id" : "spam",
    "stuff" : "eggs"
}]

//Java
List<MyClass> entries = ?
```

Anyone know if there is a magic missing command? If not then what is the solution?

Comment: I prefer Google's GSON library for dealing with JSON. It is worth checking out if you haven't tryed it yet... makes working with it very easy and intuitive.

Comment: FWIW The possible solutions to this specific problem with Gson are almost identical to what's possible with Jackson's Data Binding API.

Comment: Gweebz -- maybe you would like to explain why you feel GSON is a better choice (compared to Jackson)?

Answer (score 2313, accepted):

First create a mapper :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;// in play 2.3
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

As Array:

```
MyClass[] myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class);
```

As List:

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

Another way to specify the List type:

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MyClass.class));
```

Comment: One extra note, if while parsing you get an error such as `JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type` then it means you need to added a default constructor to your class adding a private no-arg constructor fixed it for me.

Comment: @SyntaxRules adding explicit constructor is necessary if you have an explicit constructor -- if not, compiler automatically creates public "empty" constructor. Good point. Another common problem is that inner classes need to be `static` -- otherwise they never have zero-arg constructor.

Comment: Btw, `List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class))` works up to 10 time faster than TypeRefence.

Comment: I'm looking for a generic type version.

Comment: @EugeneTskhovrebov your way is the cleanest for inlining. The others require casting or declaring. I suggest adding it as its own answer to help highlight it, and give you some rep.

Comment: Any reason why mapper.readValues() -> Iterator is not working?

Comment: For more information maybe checkout this article I found: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I'd like to know how to do the same but with a nested array like so: 
`{
  "data": [
    {...}, {...}, {...}
  ]
}`
I've spent a couple of hours now trying to figure out how to apply this to my situation.

Comment: In response to my own comment above, first parse the json string to a jsonNode and then access the property of the array like this:
```JsonNode jsonNode = MAPPER.readTree(json);
String arrayString = jsonNode.get("data").toString();```
Then follow @Programmer Bruce's instructions above.
```List<Source> sources = MAPPER.readValue(arrayString, new TypeReference<List<Source>>() {});```

Comment: @Stephane I have declared the next method to get the generic class: `private Class<E> getObjectClass() { return (Class<E>)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]; }` then I use it like this: `List<E> systemProperties = MAPPER.readValue(columnString, MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, getObjectClass()));`

Comment: I am receiving a compile time error: `readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType)`

Comment: @SyntaxRules you should add this as an additional Answer as this helped me with my case.

Comment: What if my json array is embedded in an object that I want to deserialize? How can I annotate my List object so that the conversion will be done automatically?

Comment: It's very difficult to `mock` `TypeReference`, so using array notation.

Comment: The last option did what I needed.

Comment: Is there anything like Arrays.asList but for a Set<>?

Answer (score 289):

From [Eugene Tskhovrebov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects/28982591#comment37099398_6349488)

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class))
```

This solution seems to be the best for me.

Comment: For those working with Agents in Java, Lotus Domino, this is the way to go. I tried some of the other solutions, but always got a `ResourceNotFoundException`

Comment: SyntaxRules addition in the comments for the answer above may be required for this solution as we, it was for me. I just wanted to add that so that it is not lost.

Comment: or `Arrays.asList(Json.fromJson(json.get("fieldName"), MyClass[].class))`

Comment: or `List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode.get("fieldName"), MyClass[].class))`

Comment: This is an excellent solution for the simple case of a root json array!

Answer (score 59):

For Generic Implementation:

```
public static <T> List<T> parseJsonArray(String json,
                                         Class<T> classOnWhichArrayIsDefined) 
                                         throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Class<T[]> arrayClass = (Class<T[]>) Class.forName("[L" + classOnWhichArrayIsDefined.getName() + ";");
   T[] objects = mapper.readValue(json, arrayClass);
   return Arrays.asList(objects);
}
```

Comment: Nice construct of Class<T[]>. Never saw this. Where did you find information about this?

Answer (score 50):

try this

```
List<MyClass> list = mapper.readerForListOf(MyClass.class).readValue(json)
```

Comment: This answer worked for me: Java 11, Jackson 2.10.5.

Comment: Answer worked for me, and is clear and concise. Love it.

For me, I had a generic method that passed in a Class<T> myGenericClass and was able to do:
List<T> list = mapper.readerForListOf(myGenericClass).readValue(json);
Which worked nicely for my solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Good luck testing this!

Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(byte[])" because the return value of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerForListOf(java.lang.Class)" is null

Comment: Works great ! The unsung hero

Answer (score 17):

First create an instance of ObjectReader which is thread-safe.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader objectReader = objectMapper.reader().forType(new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

Then use it :

```
List<MyClass> result = objectReader.readValue(inputStream);
```

Comment: we do get - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.FileInputStream@33fec21; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: That can be overcome by adding this extra layer of configuration to our ObjectMapper() instance:
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Comment: do not work with error Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at

Answer (score 11):

Working with an ArrayList, these different syntaxes all worked for me:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> arrayList = ...
```

**Using `objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType`:**

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, MyClass.class));
```

**Using `new TypeReference`:**

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyClass>>(){});
```

**Using `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList)`:**

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class)));
```

I can't say which one is the best to use, but I ended up using the last one:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass[].class)));
```

Answer (score 9):

I was unable to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44720865/2153273) because my linter won't allow unchecked casts.

Here is an alternative you can use. I feel it is actually a cleaner solution.

```
public <T> List<T> parseJsonArray(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
  var tree = objectMapper.readTree(json);
  var list = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (JsonNode jsonNode : tree) {
    list.add(objectMapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, clazz));
  }
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
    List<User> lstUser = null;
    JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(new File("C:\\maven\\user.json"));
    TypeReference<List<User>> tRef = new TypeReference<List<User>>() {};
    lstUser = mapper.readValue(jp, tRef);
    for (User user : lstUser) {
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }

} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

here is an utility which is up to transform json2object  or   Object2json,
whatever your pojo (entity T)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

/**
 * 
 * @author TIAGO.MEDICI
 * 
 */
public class JsonUtils {

    public static boolean isJSONValid(String jsonInString) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.readTree(jsonInString);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String serializeAsJsonString(Object object) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        objMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        objMapper.writeValue(sw, object);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    public static String serializeAsJsonString(Object object, boolean indent) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if (indent == true) {
            objMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
            objMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        }

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        objMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, object);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    public static <T> T jsonStringToObject(String content, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        T obj = null;
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        obj = objMapper.readValue(content, clazz);
        return obj;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static <T> T jsonStringToObjectArray(String content) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        T obj = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        obj = mapper.readValue(content, new TypeReference<List>() {
        });
        return obj;
    }

    public static <T> T jsonStringToObjectArray(String content, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        T obj = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
        obj = mapper.readValue(content, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz));
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: How do I parameterize the collection type?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

Json:

```
[
   {
      "question":"How are you feeling today?",
      "key":"feeling",
      "answer":"unwell"
   },
   {
      "question":"How many hours of sleep did you get last night?",
      "key":"sleep_hours",
      "answer":"8"
   },
   {
      "question":"Have you been having nightmares lately?",
      "key":"nightmares",
      "answer":"Recently"
   }
]
```

java code:

```
private String getFeelByAnswer(String answer) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        JsonNode nodes = mapper.readTree(answer);
        String feeling = "";
        for (JsonNode node : nodes) {
            if (node.get("key").asText().equals("feeling")) {
                feeling = node.get("answer").asText();
            }
        }
        return feeling;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Feeling not found.");
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you could also create a class which extends `ArrayList`:

`public static class MyList extends ArrayList<Myclass> {}`

and then use it like:

```
List<MyClass> list = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyList.class);
```