# Parse JSON to array of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, playframework-2.0

Currently I'm receiving the following JSON data in my action:

```
[
    { "civilStatus": "M" },
    "and",
    { "familySize": "2|bw|4" },
    "or",
    { "civilStatus": "D" }
]
```

I've been trying to use `play.libs.Json` to parse the string I receive at the server, but I can't find a way to obtain the array nor the objects.

I have also looked at the `org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode` documentation, but I didn't figure any way. Also I'm using Java, not Scala.

Comment: Check this question for handling array of objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found using Gson is easier.  Just add it as a dependency in Build.scala file:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    ... other dpenedencies ...
    "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.1",
    ... other dpenedencies ...
)
```

Then just parse with something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<YourCustomBean> data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<YourCustomBean>>(){}.getType());
```