# Can't parse JSON array of arrays to LinkedHashMap in Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, linkedhashmap

I' m developing an Android REST client. We use JSON as data exchange format, so I use a Jackson parser. I get different Json responses from the server like simple arrays:

```
{"user_id":"332","user_role":"1"}
```

or something else. All these stuff I parse to `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` and everything works perfectly but when I got this response from the server:

```
[ { "user_id":"352",
    "user_role":"expert",
    "name":"Test 12-18",
    "description":"Test" },

  { "user_id":"263",
    "user_role":"novice lab",
    "name":"Tom's Desk",
    "description":"Desk"}
]
```

I got null: {} after parsing.Here is my code where i use Jackson:

```
 ObjectMapper mapParametersToJSON = new ObjectMapper();
 String serverResponseBody = responseFromServer.getBody();
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> resultofOperation = new LinkedHashMap<String,
     Object>();
TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> genericTypeReferenceInformation = new
    TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>() {};
    try {
     resultofOperation =  mapParametersToJSON.readValue(serverResponseBody,
         genericTypeReferenceInformation);
```

So, why Jackson failed to parse this? How can I fix this?

Comment: why u are not using default Json Parser Api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first JSON in your question is a map, or an object. The second is an array. You're not parsing an array, you're parsing a map.

You need to do something like this:

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

Almost identical question with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects).

Comment: Ok.But is there any way to determine JSON type: object or array in order I can use some if/else when will write mapper.readvalue ?

Comment: I haven't used Jackson in production, but it appears that `JsonNode` has an `isArray()` method. My understanding is that when you're using a mapper, you generally know what you're mapping; if not, you'd probably use a DOM.

Comment: You can use Mapper to bind to `JsonNode` as well: `JsonNode root = mapper.readValueAsTree(source);`

Comment: Sweet, thanks StaxMan. Been meaning to look into Jackson anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Others have suggested the problem, but solutions are bit incomplete. If you need to deal with JSON Objects and Arrays, you can either bind to `java.lang.Object`, check the type:

```
Object stuff = objectMapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
```

and you will get either `List` or `Map` (specifically, `ArrayList` or `LinkedHashMap`, by default; these defaults can be changed).

Or you can do JSON trees with `JsonNode`:

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(json);
if (root.isObject()) { // JSON Object
} else if (root.isArray()) { ...
}
```

latter is often more convenient.

One nice thing is that you can still create regular POJOs out of these, for example:

if (root.isObject()) {
      MyObject ob = objectMapper.treeToValue(MyObject.class);
   }
   // or with `Object`, use `objectMapper.convertValue(ob, MyObject.class)`

so you can even have different handling for different types; go back and forth different representations.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON the `{"key": "value"}` is Object and the `["this", "that"]` is Array.

So, in case when you're receiving the array of objects you should use something like `List<Map<Key, Value>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an error, because `[]` construction can't be translated into `Map` reference, only in `List` or array.

I would recommend do it something in this way:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<Map<String,String>> parsedResult = objectMapper.reader(CollectionType.construct(LinkedList.class, MapType.construct(LinkedHashMap.class, SimpleType.construct(String.class), SimpleType.construct(String.class)))).readValue(serverResponseBody);

//if you need the one result map
Map<String, String> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for (Map<String, String> map: parsedResult){
    resultMap.putAll(map);
}
```