# deserialize inner JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class POJO

```
Class Pojo {
String id;
String name;
//getter and setter
}
```

I have a json like

```
{
    "response" : [
        {
            "id" : "1a",
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1b",
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Jackson ObjectMapper for deserialization. How can I get `List<Pojo>` without creating any other parent class?

If it is not possible, is it possible to get `Pojo` object which holds just first element of json string i.e. in this case `id="1a"` and `name="foo"`?

Comment: Seems similar to [this post about array deserialization.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Can I ask you why you removed the accepted answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll first need to get the array

```
String jsonStr = "{\"response\" : [ { \"id\" : \"1a\",  \"name\" : \"foo\"},{ \"id\" : \"1b\",\"name\" : \"bar\"  } ]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) node.get("response");
System.out.println(arrayNode);
List<Pojo> pojos = mapper.readValue(arrayNode.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Pojo>>() {});

System.out.println(pojos);
```

prints (with a `toString()`)

```
[{"id":"1a","name":"foo"},{"id":"1b","name":"bar"}] // the json array 
[id = 1a, name = foo, id = 1b, name = bar] // the list contents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic readTree with JsonNode:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
JsonNode response = root.get("response");
List<Pojo> list = mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<List<Pojo>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pojo pojo;
json = {
    "response" : [
        {
            "id" : "1a",
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1b",
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ]
}
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(json);
pojo = objectMapper.readValue(root.path("response").toString(),new TypeReference<List<Pojo>>() {});
```

First, you have to create a JSON node with your JSON file. Now you have a JSON node. You can go to the desired location using path function of JSON node like what I did

```
root.path("response")
```

However this will return a JSON tree. To make a String, I have used the toString method.
Now, you have a String like below
"
[
        {
            "id" : "1a",
            "name" : "foo"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1b",
            "name" : "bar"
        }
    ] "
You can map this String with JSON array as following

```
String desiredString = root.path("response").toString();
pojos = objectMapper.readValue(desiredString ,new TypeReference<List<Pojo>>() {});
```

Comment: You should also explain your answer, not just post a code.

Comment: Thanks guys, for the suggestion. I will update my answer