# How to parse JSON data without key names into a Java class structure?

Tags: java, json, jackson, anonymous-types, class-structure

I successfully followed the example [Simple Spring code to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697555/simple-spring-code-to-parse-json) into a Java class structure using Jackson.

Now i am looking for a hint how to do the same for JSON data without key names, e.g.

```
{
    "10869918": {
        "BRANCH": "Dienstleistungen", 
        "SECTOR": "Diverse"
    }, 
    "12254991": {
        "BRANCH": "Luft- und Raumfahrtindustrie", 
        "SECTOR": "Logistik"
    }, 
    "12302743": {
        "BRANCH": "Touristik und Freizeit", 
        "SECTOR": "Medien/Freizeit"
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesB I think OP referes to the fact that the keys, like 10869918, cannot be the name of any attribute in a bean. The only option here is a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

Comment: What does the POJO look like that you are trying to map this json to?

Comment: I only have the JSON data and try to create suitable POJOs which match the data using Spring-Roo as rapid prototyping tool. The actual data set is more complex then the excerpt shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible with a POJO-JSON mapper. You could use libraries like [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) to parse the JSON string into Java objects (which basically are maps and lists) and access values like `"10869918"` by reading the keys of those maps.

Comment: My idea exactly; don't map to an object, map to a collection instead. The data itself seems to represent a hashtable of sorts anyway, so it would be pretty strange to want to map that to a POJO.