# Taking values from jSONobject

Tags: java, android, json

I am working in web service.Now I want to take values from json object,so I create one parser class and pass the json object.In System.out.println("main object"+mainObj) I got the json object.But in if(mainObj!=null) I got false.so the remaining code is not working.Here return type is always null.

Following is my code,

Parser Class

```
public class JSONParser {

    private Context mContext;
    public JSONParser(Context context)
    {
        mContext=context;
    }
    public JSON_Parser_Registration[] ObjectReturner(String result)
    {
        JSON_Parser_Registration[] mJSONObj=null;
        try
        {
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println("main object"+mainObj);
            if(mainObj!=null)
            {
                JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("result");
                System.out.println("list values"+list);
                if(list != null)
                {
                    mJSONObj=new JSON_Parser_Registration[list.length()];                       
                    for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
                        System.out.println("element values"+elem);
                        if(elem != null)
                        {
                            String id=elem.getString("id");
                            String msg=elem.getString("msg");
                            mJSONObj[i]=new JSON_Parser_Registration();
                            mJSONObj[i].SetValues(id, msg);
                            System.out.println("id is "+id +" \nMessage is is "+msg);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return mJSONObj;
    }

}
```

JSON_Parser_Registration class

```
public class JSON_Parser_Registration {

    public String mId;
    public String mMessage;


    public void SetValues(String id,String msg)
    {
        mId=id;
        mMessage=msg;

    }
}
```

The JSON Object is in this format from server

```
{"result":{"id":248,"msg":"AppUser added successfully"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`result` is a `JSONObject` not a `JSONArray`.

This

```
JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("result");
```

is wrong.

```
{ // json object node
    "result": { // jsonobject result
        "id": 248, 
        "msg": "AppUser added successfully"
    }
}
```

So it should be

```
JSONObject job = mainObj.getJSONObject("result");
String id=job.getInt("id");
String msg=job.getString("msg")
```

Answer (score 0):

use jackson library. Here is the example you are looking for

[How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Why to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code

```
 JSONObject elem =new JSONObject(list.getJSONObject(i));
    if(elem != null)
    {
              String id=elem.getString("id");
              String msg=elem.getString("msg");
              mJSONObj[i]=new JSON_Parser_Registration();
              mJSONObj[i].SetValues(id, msg);
              System.out.println("id is "+id +" \nMessage is is "+msg);
    }
```