# Parse values from a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

i have the following json object

```
{
    "result": {
        "today": [],
        "week": [{
            "ride_id": "23829994",
            "trip_average_speed": "46.15",
            "trip_distance": "2.20002797646063",
            "trip_time": "2014-02-13 06:39:30+00"
        }, {
            "ride_id": "15761690",
            "trip_average_speed": "32.09",
            "trip_distance": "16.3443284767516",
            "trip_time": "2014-02-13 11:40:30+00"
        }],
        "month": []
    }
}
```

How can I get  `"today": []`, `"month": []` and week values as arrays?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: how can you get something form today? as there is no single data in it??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [google-json](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and its [user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). Unless you want something jackson specifically.

Hope this would help you get going

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("week");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String ride_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("ride_id");
    String trip_average_speed = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("trip_average_speed");
    String trip_distance = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("trip_distance");
    String trip_time = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("trip_time");
    System.out.println("ride_id");
}
```

you can get week data using above answer.. Using library called org.json.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Using Google gson library, you can easily handle Json in Java. Please refer [Userguide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and you can download jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)

Try below code to retrieve `"today": [], "month": [] and "week": []` arrays from your Json.

```
String jsonStr = "your json string";

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson (jsonStr, JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject;

//--------------- Getting week[] as Arraylist ------------------------

public class Week   
{
   private long ride_id;
   private double trip_average_speed;
   private double trip_distance;
   private String trip_time;

   //Setters and Getters for all the parameters
}

ArrayList<Week> returnedArtworks = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("week").getAsString(), new TypeToken<List<Week>>(){}.getType());

//---------------- Getting month[] as Arraylist -----------------------

public class Month   
{
   //Parameters
   //Setters and Getters for all the parameters
}

ArrayList<Month> returnedArtworks = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("month").getAsString(), new TypeToken<List<Month>>(){}.getType());

//----------------- Getting today[] as Arraylist ----------------------

public class Today   
{
   //Parameters
   //Setters and Getters for all the parameters
}

ArrayList<Today> returnedArtworks = gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("today").getAsString(), new TypeToken<List<Today>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to create POJO for your `today`, `week`, `month` and `result`. `result` class will include list of the all other three that is `today`, `week` and `month`.
Create one master POJO that contain your `result` class object say `MyJson`.Now you can directly parse this JSON into your class and from the getter method you have list of `today`,`week` and `month` array.
To parse you JSON string into class object :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyJson resultObj = mapper.readValue(str, MyJson.class);  
//get List of week  
List<Week> week =  resultObj.getResult().getWeek();
```

Your POJO classes look like :
**MyJson.java**

```
public class MyJson   
{
     private Result result;  
     //getter and setter method  
}
```

**Result.java**

```
public class Result   
{
    private List<Today> today;
    private List<Month> month;
    private List<Week> week;    
    //getter and setter method
}
```

**Today.java**

```
public class Today   
{
  private String date;  
  //other parameters and it's getter and setter method.  
}
```

**Week.java**

```
public class Week   
{
    private long ride_id;
    private double trip_average_speed;  
    //other parameters and it's getter and setter method.    
}
```

**Month.java**

```
public class Month   
{
   private String monthName;    
  //other parameters and it's getter and setter method.      
}
```