# Spring Rest Response into Array

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

So I am developing a REST application and I have the service done to return the json/xml. I have a list and I want to read it into an array. It's returned from a GET request like

```
http://localhost:8080/todo
```

I could iterate through the

```
http://localhost:8080/todo/get/1
```

and just do that through the size, but I wanted to see if I could get the whole response into an array. Its a json response that looks like:

```
[{"id":1,"task":"Assemble Team"},{"id":2,"task":"Determine Roles"},{"id":3,"task":"Split Up Work"},{"id":4,"task":"Do Individual Tasks"},{"id":5,"task":"doit"}]
```

Right now I'm using Spring Boot and it looks like

```
int i = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/todo/size", int.class);
        System.out.println("Size: " + i);
        Task quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/todo/get/3", Task.class);
```

that's to get one of the objects. but is there a way to read the entire json list into an array or something instead of iterating through, calling GET requests for each item on the list?

Should I create another class that holds an arraylist of the Task class (which just has an id and task string, and standard getters/setters)? I'm not sure how that would work.

I tried having a class that would hold a bunch of the 'quotes':

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Value {

private List<Quote> Q = new ArrayList<Quote>();

public Value() {

}

public List<Quote> getQuote() {
    return this.Q;
}


public void setList(List<Quote> quote) {
    this.Q = (ArrayList<Quote>) quote;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Q.toString();
}
```

and in the main part:

```
Value V = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/todo", Value.class);
```

But I just get

```
 Can not deserialize instance of hello.Value out of START_ARRAY token
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `List<Quote> quotes = (List<Quote>) restTemplate.getForObject(".../todo", java.util.List.class);`

Comment: I actually found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358872/how-to-convert-linkedhashmap-to-custom-java-object and used and yours together, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make use of [exchange](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperations.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.lang.Object...-) methods available in Rest Template.

```
ResponseEntity<List<Quote>> res = template.exchange(
rootUrl,
HttpMethod.GET,
null,
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Quote>>() {});
```

Comment: I think you need to declare `res` as `ResponseEntity<List<Quote>>`

Comment: This answers the question. I couldn't come up with a simpler approach. I wonder why there isn't an overload of `getForObject`.

Comment: well instead of having an overload for each of http verbs spring exposes an exchange api

Comment: Sorry, but this is a lot of code to do a simple get with parameterized return type.

Comment: yep this worked perfectly, thanks. I'll have to read up more on exchange methods, I just got into using REST with spring and there seems to be so many things to know. Just figuring out which way to use REST (jersey, boot, resteasy, etc) took me awhile.