# jackson object property into primitive

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have the follow json.

```
{
   foo:{
      id:1
   },
   name:'Albert',
   age: 32
}
```

How can I deserialize to Java Pojo

```
public class User {
    private int fooId;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @BatScream There's no array here, I believe the problem comes from the fact that in the json the id is nested in a foo object, for which there is no POJO.

Comment: Has nothing like @JsonProperty("foo.id")?

Comment: Why can't you change the structure of your POJO?

Comment: There's an example on [this wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) which is almost exactly what you're trying to do.  Just create an inner `Foo` class in `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to deserialize, using the `JsonProperty` annotations in your constructor.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

public class User {

    private int fooId;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public int getFooId() {
        return fooId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public User(@JsonProperty("age") Integer age, @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                @JsonProperty("foo") JsonNode foo) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.fooId = foo.path("id").asInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"foo\":{\"id\":1}, \"name\":\"Albert\", \"age\": 32}" ;
        try {
            User user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);

            System.out.print("User fooId: " + user.getFooId());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

`User fooId: 1`

Hope it helps,

Jose Luis

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

- Create a concrete type representing `Foo`:

  ```
  public class Foo {
      private int id;

      ...
  }
  ```

  Then in `User` you would have:

  ```
  public class User {
      private Foo foo;

      ...
  }
  ```
- Use a `Map<String, Integer>`:

  ```
  public class User {
      private Map<String, Integer> foo;

      ...
  }
  ```

If other callers are really expecting you to have a `getFooId` and a `setFooId`, you can still provide these methods and then either delegate to `Foo` or the `Map` depending on the option you choose. Just make sure that you annotate these with `@JsonIgnore` since they aren't real properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a very helpful [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip&) google API.

First of all, create these two classes:

*User class:*

```
public class User{
    Foo foo;
    String name;
    int age;
    //getters and setters
}
```

*Foo class:*

```
public class Foo{
    int id;
    //getters and setters
}
```

If you have a `example.json` file then deserialize it as follow

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User data = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "example.json")), new TypeToken<User>() {
}.getType());
```

If you have a `exampleJson` String then deserialize it as follow

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User data = gson.fromJson(exampleJson, User.class);
```