# How to convert a Json list to a list of java objects with javax.json?

Tags: java, json

How can I convert a Json list in to a List of objects with javax.json?
This is the Json

```
{"chartId":O1234567,"products":[{"productId":1,"productInfo":"wine"},{"productId":2,"productInfo":"cookies"},{"productId":3,"productInfo":"donut"}]}
```

And this are my classes.

```
public class Chart{
        private int chartId;
        private List<Product> products;

        //getters and setter
        }

  public class Product
        {
        private int productId;
        private String productInfo;
    }


  public class ConvertJson{
         public Chart convertJsonToChart(String JsonToConvert){

            InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(jsonToConvert);        
            JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(fis);       
            JsonObject jsonObject=jsonReader.readObject();       
            jsonReader.close();
            fis.close();

            Chart chart=new chart();
            chart.setChartId(jsonObject.getInt("productId"));
           //Here I should convert the productc json list to an java array list


           }
   }
```

Like u see I do know how to convert the chart json to chart java object, but how to I do that if I want to convert a json list? 
Thank you

Comment: You could use jackson or gson to deserialize your objects.

Comment: From what package classes `JsonReader`, `JsonObject` and `Json` are?

Comment: @Andremoniy from javax.json-1.0.4 and javax.json-api-1.0

Answer (score 0):

As Christoph said, you can use Jackson.
Here is a related topic that shows you how to use the library.
First create an object mapper and then read the value from json passed as a parameter in the method readValue() of the mapper.

[How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

You can read more examples about Jakson here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/

Or you can do deeper research of this library.