# Java Handling JSON response from my server

Tags: java, php, android, json

Hello im trying to handle this JSON output from my php server for my android app how would i go about doing this? what i would like (if you can do this in java) is to handle it as follows `$resArray[0]["username"]` i know this may not be possible but i will need access to each individual element

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"6",
      "username":"MasonMoo",
      "isLocked":"0",
      "isOpen":"1",
      "profileImage":"",
      "gender":"Male"
   },
   {  
      "id":"7",
      "username":"AndrewAubury",
      "isLocked":"0",
      "isOpen":"1",
      "profileImage":"",
      "gender":"Male"
   }
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android