# Spring Boot Jackson map JSON response from 3rd party API to custom Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a Java class out of a json response I get from a third party API which I have already managed to to with using the ObjectMapper. However, in this specific case, the JSON response has no keys so I dont know how I can map this into an Object, basically how should I use @JsonProperty annotation if the json response looks like this

```
[
[
1499040000000,      // Kline open time
"0.01634790",       // Open price
"0.80000000",       // High price
"0.01575800",       // Low price
"0.01577100",       // Close price
"148976.11427815",  // Volume
1499644799999,      // Kline Close time
"2434.19055334",    // Quote asset volume
308,                // Number of trades
"1756.87402397",    // Taker buy base asset volume
"28.46694368",      // Taker buy quote asset volume
"0"                 // Unused field, ignore.
]
]
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111311/5521670 and this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/parsing-json-arrays-as-objects-with-jackson-c2620e7cc439 answer your question?

Comment: the JsonpropertyOrder seems to be worth checking out indeed, however I dont see sense in use the Shapy of Array because the entity has also an api endpoint that only returns a single object instead of an array containing multiple. Can't I just leave away the Shape.Array and inside the objectmapper readvalue pass the .class with a [] prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "foo", "bar" })
public class FooBar {
  public String foo;
  public String bar;
}
```

Example here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111311/5521670
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/parsing-json-arrays-as-objects-with-jackson-c2620e7cc439

Comment: what if I got an endpoint that returns a single object instead of an array, does the custom class with the JsonFormat shape of type array still work then or can I ommit that Annotation and pass into the objectmapper readvalue method an array of type x?

Comment: ignore my previous comment, the response is always an array or an array inside an array so I think its correct.

Comment: That solution seems to work, however my own restcontrollers json response now looks exactly like the response from the 3rd party API instead of having the keys from the fields I have set via @JsonProperty Annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom dto, which has a JsonCreator to store the "state" internally and then you add alot of getters to extract each thing:

```
public class TestDto {

    private String[] data;

    @JsonCreator
    public TestDto(String[] data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return data[0];
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return data[1];
    }
    
    //etc

}
```

EDIT: if you convert it to a `List<TestDto>`, you can extract everything