# how to read json into collection knowing only Class of the entity with jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a json file witch contains a list of a given type, for example:

```
   [{
      "createdBy":"SYSTEM_INIT",
      "status":401,
      "message":"Unauthorized",
      "description":"",
      "lang":"en"
   },{
      "createdBy":"SYSTEM_INIT",
      "status":413,
      "message":"Payload Too Large",
      "description":"The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process",
      "lang":"en"
   }{....
```

I have a java class(this case call it MyClass) witch represent this one entity. 
When i want to deserialize the json into collection i only have a `Class` object, with is `MyClass.class` . How can read in to a `Collection<MyClass>`

Actually it"s a spring applicaiton and this is my current code:

```
public boolean importFromJsonFile(String table, Class clazz) {
    Collection<Object> objectCollection = new ArrayList<>();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("init/" + table + ".import.json").getFile());
        objectCollection = mapper.readValue(file, Collection.class);
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error("error: ", e);
        return false;
    }

    if(objectCollection.size() < 0){
        log.error("There is no data in the file");
        return false;
    }

    try {
        for(Object obj : objectCollection){
            save(obj, clazz);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error("fatal error: ", e);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So my problem after reading the file the result will be a Collection of `LinkedHasMap` instead of `Collection` of `MyClass` with is in this particular sample is represented by variable `clazz`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's way

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(file, MyClass[].class))
```

You can get different approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects), however, this one is faster.

Based on the comments(As It is mentioned that class variable and file is present on the runtime):

```
public List getObjects(Class<T> aClass, File file) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //Fetches Arrayed Class
    Class namedClass = Class.forName("[L" + aClass.getName() + ";");
    List myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(file, namedClass));
    return myObjects;
}
```

Comment: well this is obvious, but it's not help me, because MyClass is not constant, it can be MyCLass2 MyClass3 and ... can be a lot of class. I have a properti setting, where i expect classpaths, and get the Class object wit Class.forName(); that class should be anotated with Entity, and Table, and get table name, and the repository for it etc... So i only have the Class object of MyClass and want to create a List<MyClass> or what ever Collection or array

Comment: @Syngularity I've updated the answer, Now you can get the List on runtime

Comment: thx, it was a good starting point but it's need some fix. this line:     `List myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(file, namedClass));` create a a list with One element win on `Object`, but the class of the Object actually namedClass[].