# How to parse nested arrays with Jackson using Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, unmarshalling

Below is the Json I am converting to a POJO using jackson:

```
[
    [
        {
             "title"  : "Professional JavaScript",
             "author" : "Nicholas C. Zakas"
        },
        {
            "title" : "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
            "author" : "David Flanagan
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "title" : "High Performance JavaScript",
            "author" : "Nicholas C. Zakas"
        },
        {
            "title"  : "Professional JavaScript",
            "author" : "Nicholas C. Zakas"
        },
        {
           "title" : "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide",
            "author" : "Nicholas C. Zakas"
        }
    ]
]
```

I am getting the following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.test.sample.jsonsample out of START_ARRAY token
```

below is my class

```
public class jsonsample
{
   @JsonProperty("title")
   public String title;
   @JsonProperty("author")
   public String author;
  //getters and setters
}

public class mainclass
{
  public List<jsonsample> sjson;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<mainclass> accs = mapper.readValue(rspString,mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, mainclass.class));
```

How can I get data from the nested structure, and also with unnamed arrays?

Comment: You need another `List<>`. Your data is a list of lists

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects