# How JSON deserialize Array?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using fasterxml.jackson. I am confused about `readValue()`. Here is my question.

I know jackson deserialize normal JavaBean and Collection in two different ways.
For JavaBean, we can pass `MyBean.class` or `new TypeReference<MyBean>` to `readValue()`. For Collections, we must pass `new TypeReference<List<MyBean>>`. That is because `TypeReference` saves the type erased by Collection. Am I right? :)

Now I am confused. If `MyBean` contains a list, then I can still pass `MyBean.class` and it works. How does jackson do that?

```
public class MyBean {
    String str;
    List<String> strList;
}
```

Comment: The generic type of the strList field is available using reflection. But you can't pass a `List<MyBean>.class` as argument in Java. Only `List.class`.

Comment: Maybe this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349488/6296931

Comment: My Question is: I think JSON cannot deserialize List because of type erase. That's why we have to pass TypeReference. But if Java Bean contains List<String>, How can JSON know its generic in Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `MyBean.class` as the second argument to `readValue()` and Jackson can get the type from this through reflection. I'd guess Jackson does something like this :

```
MyBean.class.getDeclaredField("strList").getGenericType();
```

which will result in a type of `java.util.List<java.lang.String>`.

Note that you have a non generic `class MyBean` containing a `List<String>`. If you had for instance:

```
class MyGenBean<T> {
    List<T> list;
}
```

then

```
MyGenBean.class.getDeclaredField("list").getGenericType();
```

would return `java.util.List<T>` and you would need a `TypeReference`.