# JsonNode Convert JSON to list of string

Tags: java, json

I have a json in this format:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "value": "[\"1-1\",\"1-2\",\"1-3\"]"
}
```

The **success** is actually in `int` and value is a `List` of `String`, i want to get the **value** and put those elements into a `List<String>`. The List of String will be:

```
1-1
1-2
1-3
```

I actually wish to parse the entire json using JsonNode, but the problems that restrict me from doing so are:

1. `"[\"1-1\",\"1-2\",\"1-3\"]"` is wrapped with double quotes, so it
   might be treated as String.
2. Have to get rid of the backslash in the string

The following is my workaround that i tried, is there any elegant/better (It is better without regex, just parse entire json into JsonNode) way to do so?

```
 ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
 JsonNode response = mapper.readTree(payload);  //payload is the json string
 JsonNode success = response.get("success");
 JsonNode value = response.get("value");

    if (success.asBoolean()) {
        String value = value .toString();
               value = value .replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "")
                    .replace("\\", "");
       return Arrays.asList(value .split(","));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have to get rid of the backslash in the string

No, you really don't.

> so it might be treated as String.

It actually is, and the fact that you are **viewing** it as a String is the reason why the **escape characters** exist.

If you pass the `response.get("value").toString()` to an ObjectMapper parser, you should get back an array or list

[How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects#6349488)

```
List<String> values = MAPPER.readValue("[\"hello\", \"world\"]", new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
System.out.println(values); // [hello, world]
```

---

The alternative, more preferred, solution is to fix the producer of the initial JSON.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help, is the sample you posted able to solve the leading and trailing double quote problem? Because i tried it, it seems not able to parse from json to the `List<String>`. `Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: "[\"1-1\",\"1-2\",\"1-3\"]";`

Comment: `mapper.readValue` should accept a JSON string, just like your `payload` variable. Perhaps it is just `mapper.readTree(response.get("value").toString());` without a TypeReference, but that would give a JsonNode, not a List<String>