# JSON parsing Exception using Jackson - unexpected non-digit at line 1 column 2

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm kinda getting frustrated after searching and trying around everything my mind came up with...

I try to parse a JSON file into a list or array of MyObject. I found this post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects/28982591#comment37099398_6349488) and played around with the code. But now I always get the same Exception, whatever I do/change in the JSON file.

### Exception I get:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-digit at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

### What I tried:

I reduced the file to just 2 objects not containing some special stuff to make sure it works. It doesnt..

- Validating the json file with an online tool
- All different types of importing the JSON as object list/array from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects/28982591#comment37099398_6349488)
- playing around with the JSON file

### Heres the current code for importing

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(content, MyClass[].class));
```

### JSON

```
[
    {
        "name":"1000.1000",
        "maskId":"1000",
        "fieldId":"1000",
        "i18nKey":"debugLabel_1",
        "label":"Logo",
        "tooltip":" ---"
    },
    {
        "name":"1000.1000",
        "maskId":"1000",
        "fieldId":"1000",
        "i18nKey":"debugLabel_1",
        "label":"Logo",
        "tooltip":" ---"
    }
]
```

### MyClass

```
 public class MyClass{

        String name;
        String maskId;
        String fieldId;
        String i18nKey;
        String label;
        String tooltip;

        public MyClass(String name, String maskId, String fieldId, String i18nKey, String tooltip, String label) {
            this.name = name;
            this.maskId = maskId;
            this.fieldId = fieldId;
            this.i18nKey = i18nKey;
            this.tooltip = tooltip;
            this.label = label;
        }

        // Getter + Setter
    }
```

Thanks for advices in advance.

Comment: Can you add the class MyClass that you are reading into?

Comment: Your JSON seems to be valid. But there's a `:` before it in your question. Is it part of the JSON you want to parse?

Comment: It was from my heading, i removed it in the post

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact JSON you are trying to send ?

Comment: yes and it is the whole file, as is

Comment: You need a default constructor for `MyClass`. I created one, generated both getters and setters and it worked for me.

Comment: I added it but it didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your class expects to receive a number for it's property and sees string.

This should work:

```
[
    {
        "name":"1.1",
        "maskId":1,
        "fieldId":"1",
        "i18nKey":"test1",
        "label":"Test 1",
        "tooltip":"---"
    },
    {
        "name":"1.2",
        "maskId":1,
        "fieldId":"2",
        "i18nKey":"test2",
        "label":"Test 2",
        "tooltip":"---"
    }
]
```

Comment: Maybe the function actually forces the type. Can you try opposite? Like setting `maskId` to integer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
final String jsonString = gson.toJson(mapper.readValue(content, MyClass[].class);
```

try this, i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... but I still cant tell what the problem was.

I recreated all the files and Classes and nowit works... kinda strange

But thanks for the help!