# JSON Deserialization - JSON Array to ArrayList of JSON Objects

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I am trying to deserialize a string which is a JSON Array in Java using fasterxml. And I want to convert this into an ArrayList of JSONObjects.

```
[
  {
    "test": "hello"
  },
  {
    "anotherTest": "world"
  }
]
```

When I try to use the object mapper as follows,

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> list = mapper.readValue(sourceString, ArrayList.class);
```

I am getting an ArrayList which contains LinkedHashMap.

I tried to change my type using the below code.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> list = mapper.readValue(s, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, JSONObject.class));
```

And even this...

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> list = mapper.readValue(s,new TypeReference<List<JSONObject>>() {});
```

Both it did not help me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: btw, what this article is saying is to use a List instead of an ArrayList

Comment: @JacobB. I referred the above answer. And tried the approaches in the answer.Here, my problem is, I don't have a POJO. I want the element to be a simple JSONObject.