# Parsing Json file with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I call a WS that returns a Json object like follows:

```
   {
        "id": "salton", 
        "name": "salton", 
    }
```

which I parse without any problem using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Show.class);
```

Then I have another WS that return a list of objects, as follows

```
{
    "id": "saltonId", 
    "name": "salton", 
},
{
    "id": "elCordeLaCiutat", 
    "name": "elCordeLaCiutat", 
}
```

which I want to parse using

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, List<Show.class>.class);
```

but I got compilation problems

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - List cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Syntax error on token ">", byte expected after this 
     token
```

Comment: did you include java.util.List?

Comment: yes, its included in the import

Comment: why is .class inside a generic?

Comment: Use `mapper.readValue(jsonStr,                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Show.class));`

Comment: Your list of objects should be wrapped by brackets.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Just use 'mapper.readValue(jsonStr, List.class);'

Comment: @senerh, convert to anser please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of objects should be wrapped in `[]` as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": "saltonId", 
        "name": "salton", 
    },
    {
        "id": "elCordeLaCiutat", 
        "name": "elCordeLaCiutat", 
    }
]
```

which you can unmarchal like that:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Show> shows = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Show[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Show>>() {}.getType();
return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, listType.class);
```