# Error on converting json to list of strings java play framework

Tags: java, playback

I am trying to convert a json file to a list of strings, but it is throwing `expected -> error`

I've already tried `TypeReference<List<String>> List<String>` but it throws a different error each time. Look at line 28 for the error location.

Error Message:

> [error] /home/willroy/Code/playframework/database/app/controllers/HomeController.java:28:1: -> expected
>   [error]       return mapper.readValue(new File("/tmp/notes.json"), List(){});
>   [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) javac returned non-zero exit code
>   [error] Total time: 0 s, completed 12-Jun-2019 11:05:01

```java
public class HomeController extends Controller {
  public Result get() {
    return ok("")
    WS.url("localhost:9000")
      .seteContentType("/")
      .post(getJson());
  } 

  public Result post(String text) { 
    List<String> noteJson = getJson();
    noteJson.append(text);
    return ok("");  
  }

  private List<String> getJson() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(new File("/tmp/notes.json"), List<String>(){});
  }    

  private void saveJson(List<String> noteJson) {
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/tmp/notes.json");
    file.write(notJson.toJSONString());
  } 

}
```

SOLVED:

Did not import enough at the top of the file (File, List, etc...) XD.

Comment: you get compilation error cause second argument in `readValue` function should be class and not an instance of List. also take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code by using this example below :

```
private List<String> getJson() {
    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode nodes = objectMapper.readTree(new File("/tmp/notes.json")).get("list");
    if (nodes.isArray()) {
        for (final JsonNode node : nodes) {
            texts.add(node.get("property").asText());
        }
    }
    return texts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this!

Comment: Tried it and it fixed the error, however I got a load of other errors "cannot find symbol" for a load of lines (33, 28, 10, 31, 26)

Comment: But what are you trying to access ? Can you just add json to your question ?

Comment: Wait, would it matter if the json file was empty? Haven't added anything to it yet. The file does exist however.

Comment: If json is empty, then it may be objectmapper will cause a problem.

Comment: Just tried adding items to json file (["one","two","three"]) and got same error.

Comment: Nope does the same thing.

Comment: Still no, must be something else then, it seems to throw a "cannot find symbol" error every line that has List<String>, could I be doing something wrong there?

Comment: Okay, I just have not imported anything (List, File, etc) and It seems to work fine now. Thanks for the help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the Class in the second argument,

```
return mapper.readValue(new File("/tmp/notes.json"), new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, will try!

Comment: Don't forget to mark answer as correct if it helped you :D

Comment: It solved that error but I just got a load of "cannot find symbol" errors on lines 33, 28, 10, 31 and 26 XD