# List of JsonString to list of User Objects conversion

Tags: java, json

Not the duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects).

Here in the list ,items are string within double quotes.

I am trying to convert a list of messages which are jsonString to List of UserDefined objects.
I have input like this.

```
[
    "{\"id\":\"5\",\"type\":\"abc\",\"innerObject\":{\"id\":\"8\"}}"
]
```

What is the method to convert this list to List of MyClass.

```
class MyClass{
String id;
String type;
Inner inner;
//getters and setters
}
class Inner{
String id;
//getters and setters
}
```

I have tried

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

Also this

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
myList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonFormattedString, listType);
```

But not working.

Expected output is

```
[{"id":"5","type":"abc","innerObject":"8"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried Gson?

Comment: yes. I have tried this. updated query .

Comment: can you update the complete class with getters and setters

Comment: You have innerObject inside the jsonString, but the property in the MyClass is called inner and not innerObject. Can it be that the problem why it's not working?

Comment: But the error is even before that as the input list contains String with double quotes.

Comment: You should be able to iterate the string array and use `GSON`'s `fromJson` method to convert to your type. https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 0):

For the `readValue` method of `ObjectMapper`, the second argument should be the class and not a class instance. For example, if this were a single item you would call `readValue` as shown below:

```java
objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, TransEvent.class);
```

For a generic list, this can be accomplished either of the following ways:

```java
// list
objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, new TypeReference<List<TransEvent>>(){});

// list
objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, TransEvent.class));

// array
TransEvent[] transEvents = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, TransEvent[].class);
```

Comment: yes. If the object was single item. But it is list and with String items.

Comment: @user3763375 I forgot about type erasure for generics, I've updated my response

Comment: @user3763375 You can actually also use the basic array type as well, I added the example using `TransEvent[].class` just now

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker ']': expected '}' (for root starting at [Source: ] when I tried objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormattedString, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, TransEvent.class));

Comment: I think the problem is input list contains string with double quotes.