# Convert JSON to Object throws JsonMappingException "Can not deserialize instance of class out of START_ARRAY token"

Tags: java, json, rest, trello

I am trying to get information about my `Trello` boards using their `REST` API ([link](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/guides/rest-api/api-introduction/)) and save it in a Java Object. I followed the initial steps and running this command I get all the info I want:

```
curl https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?fields=name,url&key={apiKey}&token={apiToken}
```

which returns data in the following format:

```
[
  {
   "name": "Greatest Product Roadmap",
   "id": "5b6893f01cb3228998cf629e",
   "url": "https://trello.com/b/Fqd6NosI/greatest-product-roadmap"
  },
  {
    "name": "Never ending Backlog",
    "id": "5b689b3228998cf3f01c629e",
    "url": "https://trello.com/b/pLu77kV7/neverending-backlog"
  },
  //....
{
```

I create a `Board` Class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Board {
    private String name;
    private String shortLink;
    private String idBoardSource;
    private String id;
    private String url;

    public Board() {
    }

    //getters, setters
}
```

In my servlet, I execute:

```
//Get the response
String command = "curl -X GET https://api.trello.com/1/members/me/boards?fields=name,url&key={apiKey}&token={apiToken}";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
processBuilder.directory();
Process process = processBuilder.start();
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();

//Convert the InputStream into String
String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

//try to create an Board class
Board board = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Board.class);
```

However, I get an error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of gr.kotronis.trello.Board out of START_ARRAY token
```

I tried and added  `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` but the error still comes up.. I searched for similar questions about this error but I didn't find a solution..
The format of the response data is correct, so I don't understand why I am getting this error...

Comment: You need to decerialize json array as List or array.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to deserialize JSON array as java array, or java List.
Here you can find the answer [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects).