# ObjectMapper doesn't fail on trailing characters

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm having the following class:

```
public class Car{
private String id;
private String name;

public Car() {
}

public Car(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

and I use it like this:

```
String json = "{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"hh\"} {\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"ccc\"}";

    Car car;
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        car = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Car>() {
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        car = null;
    }
```

I'm expecting it to fail but instead, I get the first object in the input, the "first" car object.

why is that happening?

Comment: Please, check [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: hey, @YanKhonski I know I can do it with an array. the json parameter in my example actually comes from a file. I expect it to have one object but I want it to fail if it has more then one object.
I changed the object and remove the "," is still takes the first one instead of failing

Comment: `"{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"hh\"} {\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"ccc\"}"`
not valid json, missing comma **,** between cars objects.

Comment: I know and I expecting it to fail but the mapper.readValue functions return the first object and ignore the second. after this function, the car parameter will hold the id = 1 & name -"hh"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable [FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS) feature to throw an exception in this case:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS);
```

or since version `2.10`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS)
        .build();
```

From documentation:

> Feature that determines behaviour for data-binding after binding the
>   root value. If feature is enabled, one more call to
>   `JsonParser.nextToken()` is made to ensure that no more tokens are found
>   (and if any is found, `MismatchedInputException` is thrown); if
>   disabled, no further checks are made. Feature could alternatively be
>   called `READ_FULL_STREAM`, since it effectively verifies that input
>   stream contains only as much data as is needed for binding the full
>   value, and nothing more (except for possible ignorable white space or
>   comments, if supported by data format).
>
> Feature is **disabled by default** (so that no check is made for possible
>   trailing token(s)) for backwards compatibility reasons.

You can enable all features from `FAIL_ON_*` family to be as strict as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative.
Note, your type reference is not a `Car`, but a `List` of `Car`s.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final TypeReference<List<Car>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {};


final String json = "{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"hh\"} {\"id\":\"2\", \"name\":\"ccc\"}";
List<Car> cars = null;

try {
    cars = mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();   // TODO - Please, handle it
    cars = null;
}

System.out.println("Cars: " + cars);
```

It will print:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.yk.training.backperssure.Car>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{"id":"1", "name":"hh"} {"id":"2", "name":"ccc"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1464)

// More stack trace.,..\

Cars: null
```