# Simple way to get an array class type of a generic?

Tags: java

I've got a little code snippet that's supposed to make parsing JSON arrays simpler. My idea was originally as follows (pseudo-Java):

```
  public <T> T[] parseAsArray(String content, Class<T> valueType) {
    return objectMapper.readValue(content, T[].class); // doesn't work as you can't just go T[].class
  }
```

So then I fiddled around with the code. And then some more. And some more.

Eventually I landed at the following mess, which does work, but requires me to create a new array instance, just so I could fetch its array class type, not to mention all the casting.

```
  public <T> T[] parseAsArray(String content, Class<T> valueType) {
    Class<T[]> tArrClass = (Class<T[]>) Array.newInstance(valueType, 0).getClass();
    return (T[]) objectMapper.readValue(content, tArrClass);
  }
```

Isn't there a simpler way? All I'm really trying to do is, how can I go from `T` to `T[]` and with it to `T[].class`?

Comment: I think that you can use TypeToken (or something like that) to specify that the result will be of List<T>.

Comment: i found it  new TypeReference<List<T>>() No idea how to deal with arrays.,

Comment: here you have some string->class hax https://stackoverflow.com/a/44720865/1527544

Comment: Pass in a `Class<T[]>`? e.g. `parseAsArray(someContent, Integer[].class)`?

Comment: `Class<T[]> arrayClass = (Class<T[]>) Class.forName("[L" + classOnWhichArrayIsDefined.getName() + ";");` seems even more messy, not really what I had in mind...

Comment: @AndyTurner But that's the problem, the class type is passed in as singular object. I need to transform whatever was passed in into an array class.

Comment: @Selbi then don't pass it in as a singular object?

Comment: @AndyTurner I got no control over the other side, unfortunately.