# ObjectMapper only reads first object in JSON file

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

With this code, I am trying read all of the data from a JSON file, parse it with Jackson, remove unwanted fields, and put the remaining fields into a new file.

So far, my code works, except ObjectMapper.readTree only reads the first object in the JSON file. I know I need to loop through each object in the file, but I don't know how to iterate  through the tree.

Thank you in advance,

David Riley

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("exampleFile.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(file);


            JsonCleaner jsonCleaner = new JsonCleaner(root, (node) -> node != null);// isNumber());
            JsonNode result = jsonCleaner.removeAll();


            File cardFile = new File("masterCardList.json");
            FileWriter fileWriter;
            try {
                cardFile.createNewFile();
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(cardFile, true);
                fileWriter.write(result.toString() + ",");
                fileWriter.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
}
```

```
public class JsonCleaner {
    private final JsonNode root;
    private final Predicate<JsonNode> toRemoveCondition;

    JsonCleaner(JsonNode node, Predicate<JsonNode> toRemoveCondition) {
        this.root = Objects.requireNonNull(node);
        this.toRemoveCondition = Objects.requireNonNull(toRemoveCondition);
    }

    public JsonNode removeAll() {
        process(root);
        return root;
    }



    private void process(JsonNode node) {
        if (node.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) node;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = object.fields();
            while (fields.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
                JsonNode valueToCheck = field.getValue();
                // System.out.println(field.getKey());
                if (field.getKey() == "artist" || field.getKey() == "colors" ||
                            field.getKey() == "multiverseId" || field.getKey() == "scryfallId" ||
                            field.getKey() == "manaCost" || field.getKey() == "name" || field.getKey() == "rarity" ||
                            field.getKey() == "type" || (field.getKey() == "identifiers")) {
                    process(valueToCheck);
                } else {
                    fields.remove();
                }
            }
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) node;
            array.elements().forEachRemaining(this::process);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is valid json?

Comment: Yes, it has over 500 objects in it. My program only reads the very first object in it, and the file my program creates, only has the first object in it too.

Comment: Perhaps provide a sample of the file - is it possible root is a JSONArray??

Comment: It is very large. One object has over 50 key,value pairs in it, and there are over 500 entries. I checked  the first few entries, and they are correct. Each object begins with and ends with curly braces, and are comma-separated. It is a bit over 3 MB in size.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects seems to suggest you may be doing the wrong thing, but without a minimal input sample it's a bit hard to tell.