# How to efficiently merge two JSON Strings based on a common key

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jsonnode

I have two JSON strings which are essentially arrays of JSONObject. The two JSON strings have below structure and keys:

**JSON-1:**

```json
[
    {
        "title": "ABC",
        "edition": 7,
        "year": 2011
    },
    {
        "title": "DEF",
        "edition": 2,
        "year": 2012
    },
    {
        "title": "XYZ",
        "edition": 3,
        "year": 2013
    }
]
```

And, **JSON-2:**

```json
[
    {
        "title": "ABC",
        "price": "20"
    },
    {
        "title": "DEF",
        "price": "20"
    },
    {
        "title": "XYZ",
        "price": "20"
    }
]
```

Both these JSONs have a common key `"title"` based on which I want to merge these two JSONs, either merging JSON-2 values into JSON-1 or creating a JSON object with the merged result.

The merged result should look like below:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "ABC",
        "edition": 7,
        "year": 2011,
        "price": "20"
    },
    {
        "title": "DEF",
        "edition": 2,
        "year": 2012
        "price": "20"
    },
    {
        "title": "XYZ",
        "edition": 3,
        "year": 2013
        "price": "20"
    }
]
```

How can I achieve this by minimum looping and minimum object creation? I also can not use entity/model classes. The idea is to do it without creating any model classes.

Note: I cannot use Gson because I don't have the approval to use the same.

1. I tried to use `List<JSONObject> listObj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonOneString, new TypeReference<List<JSONObject>>(){});`,
   but I am getting an unknown property exception.
2. I tried `JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(jsonOneString);`, but I cannot proceed much further with this approach.

I know what I am doing here is highly inefficient, so looking for ways which will use no entity class, minimum new object creation and minimum loops. Kindly advise.

UPDATE: I updated the below code with a slight modification:

```
if (json1elem.get("title")!=null 
        && json2elem.get("title")!=null 
            && json1elem.get("title").equals(json2elem.get("title"))) {

    //
}
```

Comment: You "cannot use third-party libraries", yet you're already using a third-party library called Jackson.

Comment: I see what mistake I did there. What I meant by that is, Even though this problem is easily solved with Gson library, currently can't include it in our pom as it needs a lot of approvals. Hence that statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JsonNode json1 = objectMapper.readTree(jsonOneString);
JsonNode json2 = objectMapper.readTree(jsonTwoString);
for (JsonNode json1elem : json1) {
    for (JsonNode json2elem : json2) {
        if (json1elem.get("title").equals(json2elem.get("title"))) {
            ((ObjectNode) json1elem).setAll((ObjectNode) json2elem);
            break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(json1.toPrettyString());
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond. I'll try this out today. Meanwhile could you please help me to understand why is this not working for me:

List<JSONObject> listObj = objectMapper.readValue(jsonOneString, new TypeReference<List<JSONObject>>(){});

Is there a way to convert jsonOneString into a List<JSONObject> ?

Comment: Please check my UPDATE at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421). I haven't verify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JSONObject deepMerge(JSONObject source, JSONObject target) throws JSONException {
        Iterator it = source.keys();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            Object value = source.get(key);
            if (!target.has(key)) {
                target.put(key, value);
            } else {
                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                    JSONArray valueArry = (JSONArray) value;
                    for (int i = 0; i < valueArry.length(); i++) {
                        if (valueArry.get(i) instanceof JSONObject) {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) valueArry.get(i);
                            JSONObject valueJson1 = (JSONObject) jsonObj;
                            JSONArray targetArray = target.getJSONArray(key);
                            deepMerge(valueJson1, targetArray.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject valueJson = (JSONObject) value;
                    deepMerge(valueJson, target.getJSONObject(key));
                } else {
                    target.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: I assume that the parameters to method `deepMerge` are created from the sample JSON strings in the posted question. Maybe you can [edit] your answer and add code showing how to create the method parameters from the JSON strings?

Comment: Give a high-level explanation of what you need to do first and then go into code.