# InputStream does not seem to read response objects in list

Tags: java, json, api, response, inputstream

I am trying to read a response from an API endpoint. It works in Postman and appears to work when debugging my java code.

However it will not read any objects that are in the nested array.

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)  solution (in the comments someone lays out their solution to accessing objects in a nested array) yet that does not seem to have solved anything as the mapper consistently shows nothing inside the json list.

Here's my code:

```
try  {
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(inputStream);
    final JsonNode value = node.get("value");
    final JsonNode index = value.get(1);
    final String status = index.get("status").asText();
    return status;`
}
```

Here's the response that I'm trying to unpack. I'm trying to get the value of "status"

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "activityRunEnd": "2023-01-23T23:22:01.4234985Z",
        },
        {
            "status": "Succeeded"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the response that I'm currently getting when I readTree(inputStream)

```
{"value":[]}
```

InputStream does not seem to read any values inside the list

Comment: Have you checked that the input stream is returning the contents you expect? Why not read it into a string first, log that, and then pass the string to parseTree?

Comment: Further to @tgdavies. Drop inputstream and use String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");