# How to use reflection in Java to dynamically create classes?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a holding class, that only has member attributes of 'subclasses'. All the holding class's attributes are the same subclass type, but just have different variable names.

The holding class will receive a JSON object with attributes like idNo, some text, and an identifier. This identifier will point to the specific subclass that will have its attributes created.

So three parts here

1. Holding class with attributes of sub classes
2. JSON Array
3. HashMap that contains identifier to the name of the subclass like

HashMap

```java
dictionary.put("blue", "two");
dictionary.put("black", "one");
dictionary.put("red", "three");
dictionary.put("green", "four");
```

The JSON array is something like

```json
[{
      "identifier": "blue",
      "invoId": 1,
      "questNo": 1,
      "seqId": "1a",
      "answerText": 1
  }, {
      "identifier": "red",
      "invoId": 1,
      "questNo": 2,
      "seqId": "2a",
      "answerText": 0
  }, {
      "identifier": "green",
      "invoId": 1,
      "questNo": 3,
      "seqId": "3a",
      "answerText": 1
  }, {
      "identifier": "black",
      "invoId": 1,
      "questNo": 4,
      "seqId": "4a"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the JSON array has a colour, the HashMap has a colour to a number, and that number specifies which subclass to construct.

Holding class

```java
public class HoldingClass {
    private SubClass one;
    private SubClass two;
    private SubClass three;
    private SubClass four;
```

Subclass

```java
public class SubClass<T> {
    private String identifier;
    private String seqId;
    private int questNo;
    boolean answerText;
    private int invoId = 1;
```

The part I cannot figure out, is how to use reflection such that, it points to a specific subclass attribute in the holding class, then constructs that subclass of the specific array element's info.

I tried this method, but it didn't seem to work:

```java
public <T> SubClass constructClass(String className, String identifier, String seqId, int questNo, boolean answerText) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    Class parameters[] = new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, Object.class};
    Constructor<?> constructor = String.class.getConstructor(parameters);
    return (SubClass) constructor.newInstance(parameters);
}
```

I have this method to construct the classes

```java
public void HoldingClass3(String subclassType, String identifier, String seqId, int questNo, boolean answerText) {
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(subclassType);
        SubClass instance = (SubClass) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class, int.class, boolean.class)
                .newInstance(identifier, seqId, questNo, answerText);
        if ("one".equals(subclassType)) {
            one = instance;
        } else if ("two".equals(subclassType)) {
            two = instance;
        } else if ("three".equals(subclassType)) {
            three = instance;
        } else if ("four".equals(subclassType)) {
            four = instance;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when I call the method such as

```java
holdingClass.HoldingClass3("one", "hello", "hello", 1, true);
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: one
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:475)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:121)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:382)
    at Reflection.HoldingClass.HoldingClass3(HoldingClass.java:43)
    at com.Nicolaus.Spring.Fundamentals.SpringFundamentalsApplication.main(SpringFundamentalsApplication.java:41)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you want is to deserialize a JSON object to a specific subclass based on a property in that JSON object. Then I have good news: Many JSON libraries offer that feature out of the box! For example, Jackson has the `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` annotations to manage that.

Comment: HI! Thank you for your comment!

Right, but what If I don't have access to those libraries. But actually, let's say I do have access to the libraries, how does one specify the construction of a specific class in a class? I hope my question makes sense. Like how do I specify create subclass One?

Comment: That's a very different question. But the short answer is: you can create instances from a `Class` using the `newInstance` method: `One.class.newInstance()`

Comment: Right, I tried this but it didnt work

    public <T> SubClass constructClass(String className, String identifier, String seqId, int questNo, boolean answerText) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Class parameters[] = new Class[]{String.class, Integer.class, Object.class};
        Constructor<?> constructor = String.class.getConstructor(parameters);
        return (SubClass) constructor.newInstance(parameters);
    }

Comment: actually let me put that in the post

Comment: Parametrized Type T of SubClass is not used, so update your question if you use it, or delete the parametrized type.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your comment. I have removed the parametrized type and added some code to the post to show what im doing but still can't get it work. Would you have any idea what I would be doing wrong?

Comment: Whith latest versions of java you can format your JSson in a human-readable way using text blocks even in java. If you don't mind I would edit this.

Comment: Using metaclass is overkill in this case, it's a classical case of Json deserialization, you can use Jackson with standard classes. Your question is a little too broad between the hashmap and you json, we can't understand the relation between theses 2. To make it short: concentrate your question on json deserialisation, and i'm sure there is already an answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Hi Pdem, thank you for you comment. I see, i will edit. The main issue I'm trying to tackle is trying to find a way to use the reflection new instance to generate specific subclasses, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Please include the definitions for your subclasses. Do you actually have classes named `one`, `two`, etc?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your comment. I do have them named one, two, etc. Well, the holding class consists of 4 subclasses, and they are named one,two,three,etc. I'm having issues like, figuring a way to have a function construct specific subclass(one or two or three) and pass in the parameters to construct

Comment: *The holding class consists of 4 subclasses, the subclasses being the same kind of class

Comment: Your use of terms is wrong. You don’t have a subclass or well, to be formally correct, your two classes are subclasses of `java.lang.Object` which is irrelevant here. You just have two ordinary classes. And `HoldingClass` does not “consists of 4 subclasses”, it just has four fields of type `SubClass`, which is a bad name as the purpose of the class is not do be a subclass (and it’s not a subclass of anything special). And there’s no recognizable reason in your posted code to use Reflection at all. You can simply use `SubClass instance = new SubClass(identifier, seqId, questNo, answerText);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need reflection for this...
Look at this JUnit test:

HoldingClass:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HoldingClass {
    
    private SubClass one;
    private SubClass two;
    private SubClass three;
    private SubClass four;
    
}
```

SubClass:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SubClass {
    
    private String identifier;
    private String seqId;
    private int questNo;
    boolean answerText;
    private int invoId = 1;
    
}
```

TestClass:

```
package com.paulmarcelinbejan.stackoverflow;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class StackOverflow {

    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    
    List<SubClass> subClasses;
    
    Map<String, BiConsumer<HoldingClass, SubClass>> actions = new HashMap<>();
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws IOException {
        
        actions.put("one", (holdingClass, subClass) -> holdingClass.setOne(subClass));
        actions.put("two", (holdingClass, subClass) -> holdingClass.setTwo(subClass));
        actions.put("three", (holdingClass, subClass) -> holdingClass.setThree(subClass));
        actions.put("four", (holdingClass, subClass) -> holdingClass.setFour(subClass));
        
        dictionary.put("blue", "two");
        dictionary.put("black", "one");
        dictionary.put("red", "three");
        dictionary.put("green", "four");
        
        subClasses = readListFromFile(JSON_FILE, SubClass.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testHowToUseReflectionInJavaToDynamicallyCreateClasses() {
        HoldingClass holdingClass = new HoldingClass();

        for(SubClass subClass : subClasses) {
            String dictionaryValue = dictionary.get(subClass.getIdentifier());
            actions.get(dictionaryValue).accept(holdingClass, subClass);
        }
        
        assertNotNull(holdingClass.getOne());
        assertNotNull(holdingClass.getTwo());
        assertNotNull(holdingClass.getThree());
        assertNotNull(holdingClass.getFour());
    }
    
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    
    private static final File JSON_FILE = new File("src/test/resources/SubClasses.json");
    
    private static <R> List<R> readListFromFile(final File file, final Class<R> contentClass) throws IOException {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(file, OBJECT_MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, contentClass));
    }
    
}
```

Let me know if I didn't understand the question well.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer! Truly appreciate it. I am trying to set up your code on an env now, but can I ask, so the correct subclasses would be constructed with the correct json stuff? such that, subclass 1 will be constructed with the properties of jsonObject blue?

Comment: According to dictionary, blue is mapped to HoldingClass field “two”

Comment: HoldingClass field “one” is mapped with black.

Comment: @AJuniorDev is that correct?